# How to find SSIS package thats calling / Executing a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis

How to find SSIS package that's calling / Executing a stored procedure?

May I know a SQL query OR some other way to see which SSIS package is calling / executing a stored procedure?

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Did you try "select  sj.[name], sjs.step_name, sjs.command 
from msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs ON sj.job_id = sjs.job_id" ?